# Evaluate $\int \frac {dx}{2x}$ by different methods

Tags: integration

A problem came up in my math class that had some interesting properties: $$I=\int  \frac {dx}{2x}$$ 
Obviously this can be solved simply by removing the constant $1/2$ from the integral:

$$I=\int  \frac {dx}{2x}  = \frac 1 2 \int  \frac {dx}{x}  = \frac 12  \ln|x| + C.$$

Another student tried solving it using the following method: 
Set $u = 2x$, so $du = 2dx.$
$$
\begin{align} 
I=&\int  \frac {dx}{2x} \\
 =&\int  \frac {dx}{u}  \\
 =& \frac 12  \int \frac 2u  dx \\ 
 =&\frac 12  \int \frac {du}u \\ 
 I=&\frac 12 \ln|u|  \\
 I=& \frac 12 \ln|2x| \\
\end{align}
$$
Obviously, $(1/2) \ln|2x|$ does not always equal $(1/2)\ln|x|$. But I can't find any math errors in either method of calculating the integral. Can someone explain this discrepancy? Thank you.

Comment: $(1/2)\log |x| +(1/2)\log 2=(1/2)\log|x|+C$, now compare.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 6):

$\ln (2x)=\ln 2 + \ln x$, so they differ by a constant.  The difference is absorbed in the constant of integration.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int \frac {dx}{2x}$$
Substitute $$u=2x \implies du =2dx$$
$$
\begin{align}
I=&\frac 12 \int \frac {du}{u} \\ 
I=&\frac 12 \ln{u}+C \\
I=&\frac 12 \ln{ |2x|}+C \\ 
I=&\frac 12 \ln{ |x|}+ \underbrace {\frac 12 \ln 2+C}_{\text {Constant}} \\ 
I=&\frac 12 \ln{ |x|}+ K \\
\end{align}
$$ 
It gives the same answer whatver the method used.You just forgot the constant in the second method.